# Install RevTex 4.1 in MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: miktex, revtex

I am having a problem with installing/upgrading the revtex package in miktex. Using the upgrading feature leads nowhere because it seems that the new revtex package was not added on the update list. I have tried to install it manually but I can't make it work. I have followed the instructions from the readme file but they seem incomplete.

My questions are as follows:
1) how can I install the new version of the revtex package for the miktex distribution on windows.
2) how can I check if the right package is installed properly (i.e. what version of a package is actually used)

Cheers

Comment: Get the zip http://journals.aps.org/files/revtex/revtex4-1.zip, unpack the included tds-zip to some folder "revtex" (outside your miktex). Then add the root folder "revtex" as a new root in miktex settings. Check in the log-file if the correct files are used.

Comment: ok thank you, I will give this a go later this evening (I am at work now and don't have a windows computer here). I am sure I tried that but I was getting some errors when compiling their example document. I think this upgrade procedure should be simpler...

Comment: ok i have managed to do it by uninstalling miktex and installing texlive. much better now!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in the comments

Comment: I agree to close the question although the initial issue (installing revtex4-1 in miktex) has not been confirmed that it is working! The solution (for me anyway) was to install TexLive. Some people may not have this option...